# How async approach to rest api can reduce thread count?

Tags: node.js, multithreading, rest, asynchronous, vert.x

Many people are saying that modern rest apis should be "async", and as a main argument they say that on some platforms, for example in Java, "blocking" way of doing things produce many threads and "async" way allows to limit thread count and overhead.

What I don't understand, is how it is achieved.

Consider I have an app in a framework like vert.x (but actually it doesn't matter, you can think of NodeJS as well), and say 1_000_000 concurrent connections for a service which makes some request to a database. The framework allows each request itself to be processed async on the long task i|o operations, so database data exchange looks syntactically asynchronous in the business logic code. BUT. As I understand, DB request is made not in the vacuum - it is processed in some other thread, and that thread actually blocks until db request is finished. So it means, that despite the fact, that request business logic looks async and non blocking, long time operations which are called from such logic are actually blocking somewhere under the hood of framework and the more such operations are done, the more threads should be consumed anyway (for NodeJS you can think of threads, created in C++ code of a framework itself)

So as I see the big picture - in async approach there is only one thread, which processes all the requests, it's ok, but there is a bunch of threads, which are doing the actual I/O work in the background anyway, and if one doesn't limit their count, then the number of threads will be the same as for a blocking approach + 1. On the other hand if you limit the number of background thread pool programmatically, then what will be the benefits compared to the blocking approach, which combines a queue for user requests and a limit for the number of request processing threads?

Comment: If database is on another computer, then making a db request will be a non-blocking, non-threaded networking operation.  Thus big gain in scalability on the computer making the DB request.  Plus, nothing says that the DB itself must use threads and blocking requests.  It could be written mostly with asynchronous I/O too.  Plus, most DBs that do use threads, will work out of a thread pool since there's no advantage to trying to work on 1000 requests at a time anyway.  So, if calling code is async and DB uses a small thread pool, then you get much better efficiency than one thread per request.

Comment: When saying that db request is non blocking, you mean, that db interaction library should use the same approach as for http: some kind of non blocking loop, which iterates over a set of buffers with db response data and if it finds some new data - it activates an appropriate callback?

Comment: I'm just saying that a good DB will have some scheme for handling lots of simultaneous requests that is not just one thread per request. One thread per request is well known to not be the best way to handle lots of requests in flight at the same time because there's too much memory and context switching.There are several approaches. Plus keep in mind that a DB is usually at least another process and often on another server. If it's in another process on the same server, the last thing you want is the http server using one thread per request and then the DB using one thread per request.

Comment: Can you give me an example of some scheme for handling lots of simultaneous requests? I just can't understand how it works on a lower level.

Comment: A common scheme is a work queue and a set of worker threads or worker processes that take items from the queue and process them.  The number of simultaneous workers is tuned based on the system (number of CPUs, amount of memory, what else is happening on the server, etc...).  Another scheme is to use async I/O for everything and very few actual threads.  Some operating systems have true async disk I/O now to build on.  Another scheme is a thread pool which ends up working similarly to the queue once all the threads in the thread pool are busy.

Comment: Ok. Let's consider real life example. I have an application which uses Postgresql and AWS Dynamodb. The application is in Java so it's using Postgresql jdbc driver and AWS Java api. As I understand Postgresql driver for Java is blocking (besides, what about other languages?) and AWS Java Api just simulates async (it provides async api, but it's just a wrapper on a thread pool which sends blocking requests to AWS). Does it mean that AWS and Postgresql just did not switch the paradigm yet, or they make a stake on the blocking way of doing things?

Comment: Here is an interesting discussion. http://mikemainguy.blogspot.ru/2015/05/the-myth-of-asynchronous-jdbc.html

People insist that databases like postgresql do not support truly async requests yet regardless language client. So does it mean, the system, which uses such dbs, should necessarily be sync and it's useless to implement reactor pattern code with some supporting framework?

Comment: @jfriend00: All major OSes have had async disk I/O for a long time now (Linux took a long time to catch up) but it's messy to deal with because they all do it differently and not all have the same level of support. Tcl has had async disk I/O without thread pools since the late 90s

Comment: @slebetman - Yet, node.js doesn't use true async disk I/O - still using a thread pool (why is that?).  From what I can tell, it is not a widely used feature.  One would hope that people making their living off high performance disk I/O (database makers) would be using it when appropriate, but I don't really know off-hand.

Comment: @jfriend00: See my answer. It's messy and node devs don't want to deal with it. As I said. Tcl has done it for years. My point being, async disk I/O is not as new as some people think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're asking a fairly low level question I'll answer with a low level answer. Hope you're comfortable with C.

First, a disclaimer: I'll be talking mostly about networking code because the only widely used database I know of that use file I/O is sqlite. Since you're asking about postgres I can assume you're interested about how socket I/O (be it TCP socket or unix local sockets) can work with only one thread.

At the core of almost all async systems and libraries is a piece of code that looks like this:

```
while (1)
{
  read_fd_set = active_fd_set;

  // This blocks until we receive a packet or until timeout expires:
  select(FD_SETSIZE, &read_fd_set, NULL, NULL, timeout);

  // Process timed events:
  timeout = process_timeout();

  // Process I/O:
  for (i = 0; i < FD_SETSIZE; ++i) {
    if (FD_ISSET(i, &read_fd_set)) {
      if (i == sock) {
        /* Connection arriving on listening socket */
        int new;
        size = sizeof(clientname);
        new = accept (sock,(struct sockaddr *) &clientname, &size);
        FD_SET (new, &active_fd_set);
      }
      else {
        /* Data arriving on an already-connected socket. */
        if (read_from_client(i) < 0) {
          close (i);
          FD_CLR (i, &active_fd_set);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

(code example paraphrased from a [GNU socket programming example](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Server-Example.html))

As you can see, the code above uses no threading whatsoever. Yet it can handle many connections simultaneously. If you take a look at the for loop it is also obvious that it is basically a simple state machine that processes sockets one at a time if they have any packets waiting to be read (if not it is skipped by the `if (FD_ISSET...)` statement).

Non-I/O events can logically only come from timed events. And that's where the timeout management (details not shown for clarity) comes in. All I/O related stuff (basically almost all your async code) gets called back from the `read_from_client()` function (again, details omitted for clarity).

There is zero code running in parallel.

#### Where does the parallelization come from?

Basically the server you're connecting to. Most databases support some form of parallelism. Some support mulththreading. Some even support node.js or vert.x style parallelism by supporting asynchronous disk I/O (like postgres). Some **configurations** of databases allow higher level of parallelism by storing data on more than one server via partitioning and/or sharding and/or master/slave servers.

That's where the big parallelism comes from -- parallel computing. Most databases have very strong support for read parallelism but weaker support for write parallelism (master/slave setups for example allow you to write only to the master database). But this is still a big win because most apps read more data than they write.

#### Where does disk parallelism come from?

The hardware. Mostly this has to do with DMA which can transfer data without the CPU. DMA is not one thing. It is more like a concept. Different systems like the PCI bus, SATA, USB even the CPU RAM bus itself has various kinds of DMA to transfer data directly to RAM (and in the case of RAM, to transfer data higher up to the various levels of CPU cache) or to a faster buffer.

While waiting for the DMA to complete. The CPU is not doing anything. And while it is doing nothing and there happens to be a network packet coming in or a `setTimeout()` expiring the code that handles them can be executed on the CPU. All while a file is being read into RAM.

#### But Node.js docs keep mentioning I/O threads

Only for disk I/O. It's not impossible to do async disk I/O with a single thread. Tcl has done that for years and many other programming languages and frameworks have too. It's just very-very messy since BSD does it differently form Linux which does it differently from Windows and even OSX may be subtly different form BSD even though it is derived from it etc. etc.

For the sake of simplicity and solid reliability node developers have opted to process disk I/O in separate threads.

Note that even for socket I/O it is not as simple as the code example I gave above. Since `select()` has some limitations (for example, you're forced to loop over ALL sockets to check for incoming data even though most won't have incoming data), people have come up with better APIs. And obviously different OSes do it differently. That is why there are a lot of libraries created to handle cross platform event processing like libevent and libuv (the one node.js uses).

#### OK. But postgres still runs on my PC

Asynchronous, event-oriented systems does not **automagically** give you performance superpowers. What they DO give you is choice: the app server is blazing fast so where you put your database servers and what database you use us up to you.

#### OK. But I can do this with threads. Why async?

Benchmarks.

Since 1999, many people have run many benchmarks and in the majority of cases single threaded (or low thread count), event-oriented systems have outperformed simple multithreaded systems. It was especially true in the old days of single CPU, single core servers. It is still partly true now (since cores are still limited).

That is why Apache was re-written into Apache2 to use a thread pool of async listeners and why Nginx was written from scratch to use a thread pool of async code.

Yes, on modern servers ideally you'd still want some threads in order to use all your CPUs. The alternative is a process pool like how the cluster module works in node.js. But you'd want the number of threads/processes to be constant or as constant as possible to avoid the overhead of context switching and thread creation.

Comment: Thx for an extremely detailed answer, I appreciate it! Let me ask you one more question
Consider, I have an application which uses Postgresql and AWS Dynamodb. The application is in Java so it's using Postgresql jdbc driver and AWS Java api. Postgresql driver impl for Java is blocking and AWS Java Api only simulates async calls (it provides async api, but it's just a wrapper on a thread pool which sends blocking requests to AWS).
As I understood from your answer, socket communication is not fundamentally blocking, so does it mean I just need other libs to make a  true async impl for my task?

Comment: If the drivers are blocking then you may need to write a non-blocking driver. This is what makes node.js so successful and is also what makes writing non-blocking code so difficult in other languages. Node.js **does not have this problem of blocking drivers** for two reasons: One, form the beginning all node.js APIs were designed to be non-blocking (thought they sometimes do have blocking versions also). Two, the entire js community puts a lot of peer pressure to make everyone write non-blocking code.

Comment: Also, forgot to mention. The actual call to `read()` or `recv()` happen synchronously though they may be non-blocking. Non-blocking and async actually mean different things though they are often used together so people tend to use the terms interchangeably. Non-blocking means that reading the data may not return everything. Basically the read function may return early so APIs need to provide ways to figure out if there are any more data to read. Async is basically the `select()` function above: it is an event-based design pattern.

Comment: Thx again. Actually in my case it's impossible to switch technology, so I should remain with Java and will try to find solutions in that field

Answer (score 0):

This is true to some async frameworks where JDBC client is still synchronised. 
When querying DB in Vert.x you reuse same application threads.
Please see the following example:

```
@Test
public void testMultipleThreads() throws InterruptedException {
    Vertx vertx = Vertx.vertx();

    System.out.println("Before starting server: " + Thread.activeCount());

    // Start server
    vertx.createHttpServer().
            requestHandler(httpServerRequest -> {
                //      System.out.println("Request");
                httpServerRequest.response().end();
            }).
            listen(8080, o -> {
                System.out.println("Server ready");
            });

    // Start counting threads
    vertx.setPeriodic(500, (o) -> {
        System.out.println(Thread.activeCount());
    });

    // Create requests
    HttpClient client = vertx.createHttpClient();

    int loops = 1_000_000;
    CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(loops);

    for (int i = 0; i < loops; i++) {
        client.getNow(8080, "localhost", "/", httpClientResponse -> {
            // System.out.println("Response received");
            latch.countDown();
        });
    }

    latch.await();
}
```

You'll notice that the number of threads doesn't change, even though you serve as many connections as you would like. You can also add Vert.x JDBC client to test it.